# Strip prefix from attribute value

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

For a project, I'm stuck with XSLT-1.0/XPATH-1.0 and need a fast way to strip a lowercase prefix from attribute values.

Example attribute values are:

```
"cmdValue1", "gfValue2", "dTestCase3"
```

The values I need are:

```
"Value1", "Value2", "TestCase3"
```

I came up with this XPath expression but it is too slow for my application:

```
substring(@attr, 1 + string-length(substring-before(translate(@attr, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', '..........................'), '.')))
```

In essence the above does replace all uppercase chars to dots, then creates a substring from the original attribute value starting from the first found dot position (first uppercase char).

Does anyone know a shorter/faster way to do this in XSLT-1.0/XPATH-1.0?

Comment: That's nifty.  I can't think of a better way to do it in one XPath expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to calculate the prefix's length and manually extract the substring. Instead, just directly ask for everything that comes after it:

```
substring-after(@attr, 
                substring-before(translate(@attr, 
                                           'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                                           '..........................'), 
                                 '.'))
```

This isn't a huge improvement, but it might shave 7-8% (based on some really rough and quick tests).

Answer (score 3):

There are not many functions in XSLT 1.0 which we could use instead, so I tried the following recursive template to avoid the use of the translate function.

Because it is 1.5 times slower, it does not answer your question. I can just avoid someone trying the same thing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xml:space="default" exclude-result-prefixes="" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<out>
  <xsl:call-template name="removePrefix">
    <xsl:with-param name="prefixedName" select="xml/@attrib" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</out>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="removePrefix">
<xsl:param name="prefixedName" />
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="substring-before('_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', substring($prefixedName, 1,1))">
    <xsl:call-template name="removePrefix">
      <xsl:with-param name="prefixedName" select="substring($prefixedName,2)" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="$prefixedName" />
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```